# Migration to wicket 1.5 - jQuery, jGrowl and ajax issues

Tags: jquery, ajax, wicket, wicket-1.5

After migrating wicket from 1.4 to wicket 1.5 I ecounter really weird issue - my ajax "fields" does not work and there are errors (found via firebug) with my jQuery and jGrowl libraries.

After reading [migration guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Migration+to+Wicket+1.5) I have changed my *.java files where JS libraries were included into this (I include one of "main" class):

```
@Override
    public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
        // JQUERY
        //val header = JSLib.getHeaderContribution(VersionDescriptor.alwaysLatest(Library.JQUERY));
        //header.renderHead(response);
        //val header1 = JSLib.getHeaderContribution(VersionDescriptor.alwaysLatest(Library.JQUERY_UI));
        //header1.renderHead(response);
        response.renderJavaScriptReference(new CommonResourceRef("js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"));
        response.renderJavaScriptReference(new CommonResourceRef("js/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js"));

        // MSDROPDOWN
        response.renderJavaScriptReference(new CommonResourceRef("js/jquery.msdropdown.js"));
        response.renderJavaScriptReference(new CommonResourceRef("js/languageDropDown.js"));
        response.renderCSSReference(new CommonResourceRef("css/msdropdown.css"));

        // JGROWL
        response.renderJavaScriptReference(new CommonResourceRef("js/jquery.jgrowl_minimized.js"));
        response.renderCSSReference(new CommonResourceRef("css/jquery.jgrowl.css"));
        response.renderCSSReference(new CommonResourceRef("css/jgrowl-page.css"));     
        response.renderOnLoadJavaScript("$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) { return submitButtonOnEnter(e); });");

        // disables warning on page leaving with displayed modal (if unloadConfirmation == false)
        if (!unloadConfirmation)
            response.renderOnLoadJavaScript("Wicket.Window.unloadConfirmation = false;");
    }
```

On one of my pages, I do have included those libraries (again, checked with firebug) but I do get this errors:

> TypeError: $.jGrowl is not a function
>   Wicket.Event.add(window, "domready", function(event) {
>   $.jGrowl('close');;});
>
> TypeError: $(...) is null
>   $("#middlebar > .menu > li > a").click(function() {
>
> TypeError: $(...).bind is not a function
>   ...t.add(window, "load", function(event) { $(document).bind('keydown',
>   function(e) ...

As for my ajax fields, they are not working (when I submit field, nothing happens). I noticed that this project is using AjaxRequestTarget (meaby I migrated it wrong?). Unfortunetly I do have little knowledge about how ajax works with wicket and I was only able to find this, that I believe is creating ajax "question".

```
public class PageAjaxEventBehavior extends AjaxEventBehavior {
[...]
    public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
        CharSequence handler = Strings.replaceAll(Strings.escapeMarkup(getEventHandler().toString()), "&#039;", "'");
        String jqueryCall = String.format("$.ajax({ url: '%s', success: function(data) { $('.result').html(data); alert('Load was performed.'); } });",
                                          getCallbackUrl());

        String eventHandler = String.format("$(window).bind(\"%s\", function() {%s;});", getEvent(), jqueryCall);

        if (!closed)
            JavaScriptUtils.writeJavaScript(RequestCycle.get().getResponse(), eventHandler);

        closed = true;
    }
[...]
}
```

I do not know what else should I include so if you think that question is missing something let me know. Note that in wicket 1.4 everythink work correctly.

I also noticed that `Wicket.Event.add(window, "domready", function(event) { $.jGrowl('close');;});` is rendering on my page before jGrowl library is included, in 1.4 its rendering after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `super.renderHead(response)` as a very first line in your method.